# Is it possible to trade Pokemon from one Nintendo DS emulator to another?

Tags: pokemon-series, emulation, desmume

Is it possible to trade Pokemon from say, my phone's NDS Emulator to a PC NDS Emulator, in order to evolve for Pokemon like Slaking or Garchomp?

I'm using NDS on my phone and Desmume on PC.

Comment: there is likely no way for 2 emulators to communicate. even when using 2 different PC emulators chances are they won't communicate.

Comment: Just a reminder that no links to roms or pirated content should be allowed here. Not saying it was linked but please keep that in mind. Discussion of theoretical emulation capabilities is different as emulators are presumed legal (barring copyright violation) so long as no code is taken from the original machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Since networking is disabled on emulators, it is not possible.

[Desmume website](http://desmume.org/) states that wifi is not emulated and not supported. I assume the case is the same with the other emulator.

[Another source](https://www.reddit.com/r/emulation/comments/2z6gvv/is_there_a_way_to_connect_2_nintendo_ds_emulator/) (thanks [@Robotnik](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28182/robotnik))

Comment: And according to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emulation/comments/2z6gvv/is_there_a_way_to_connect_2_nintendo_ds_emulator/), Desmume devs deliberately removed the early stages of Wifi support after a legal threat from Nintendo

Comment: Long time since I played pokemon, but can't you trade via IR connexion? And is that supported/emulated if both emulator processes are on the same machine?

Comment: @Robotnik That seems odd. Aren't the emulators themselves allowed so long as no pirated content is bundled and so long as no actual code is copied from the original machine? Or was it just that the *threat* was enough to scare them from doing it?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - That's what I would've thought too. I'm not part of the Desmume team so I don't have the exact details, But my gut tells me that Nintendo probably wanted to stop emulators from being able to interact with real hardware and vice versa.

Comment: @Robotnik and *that* they would have a legal right to preventing.

Answer (score 0):

There are emulators that can emulate multiple machines at once.

This means that you can play the same game on four virtual machines that are connected, if memory serves me right.

I recall that this is possible in the "no$gba" emulator. This will give you the Pokemon available via trading, but if there are Pokemon only available in the other game version of said generation, you won't be able to get those.

Comment: Not possible for DS or 3DS emulators.

Answer (score 0):

## You can with [PokeGen](http://archive.pokedit.com/download/pokegen.php)

Although unofficial it accomplishes the same thing exact thing in the end.

> PokeGen is a Windows Utility that allows you to edit the save file of NDS Pokemon games.
>
> You can also Generate Action Replay Codes, modify the PokeDex, add
> Wonder Cards, edit Items, and edit C-Gear skins.

---

> - Compatible Games   Pokemon Black 2, White 2, Black, White, HeartGold,    SoulSilver, Platinum, Diamond, and Pearl.
> - Compatible OS  Windows XP, Vista, 7, and 8.

---

Just make sure the OT (Original Trainer), where it was caught, cartridge version, etc., match what you want.

You can manually trade all the way from first generation to the latest version. Depending on how anal you want to be you can follow this [extremely long, detailed, and interesting tutorial](http://timespentgaming.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-great-pokemon-rom-migration-of-our.html)

**This is the only way to move Pokemon from one emulator save to another.**

Comment: This is technically an answer. It says no other method is available meaning that wireless communication is impossible.